# How to delete a particular shard from a cluster in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am doing M103: Basic Cluster Administration from MongoDB University.

During the chapter "Setting Up a Sharded Cluster" I successfully configured one Shard. Then in next LAB "Chapter 3: Sharding Lab - Configure a Sharded Cluster" asked to add another shard, which I did it successfully. As their are two shard added in same mongos while run the validate the script it's return a message.

validate_lab_first_sharded_cluster

Mongos not configured correctly - make sure you have only added one shard to
your cluster.

I tried to remove the old shard, which is also not getting removed, it remain in "draining ongoing" state. I tried to see the mongodb documentation but not able to figure out properly.

I am new in MongoDB, if anyone can help me. Below is the removeshard output

```
    db.adminCommand( { removeShard: "m103-example" } )
{
        "msg" : "draining ongoing",
        "state" : "ongoing",
        "remaining" : {
                "chunks" : NumberLong(0),
                "dbs" : NumberLong(3)
        },
        "note" : "you need to drop or movePrimary these databases",
        "dbsToMove" : [
                "m103",
                "newDB",
                "test"
        ],
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1578886498, 1),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1578886498, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"cKZMZd4580YsaLBTA3lx7xEWHYc="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("6781065834904158234")
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are following the steps from this docs: [Remove Shards from an Existing Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/remove-shards-from-cluster/).

Comment: You miss [Move Databases to Another Primary Shard](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/remove-shards-from-cluster/#move-databases-to-another-primary-shard)

Comment: @Prasad_57 I followed the same document.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit Those dbs are no longer exists.

MongoDB Enterprise m103-example:PRIMARY> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.001GB
MongoDB Enterprise m103-example:PRIMARY>